# Dealing with sections when converting tex to html using make4ht

Tags: ubuntu, html, make4ht, texlive-2020

I am trying to convert a math book from tex to html. Here is my sample code

```
\documentclass[ebook,oneside,openany,ngerman]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chaptername1}
\section{Sectionname1}
\begin{align}
\neg  \left( \bigwedge_x A(x) \right) = \bigvee_x \neg A(x) \label{negAQ}
\end{align}
There is at least a $x$, s.t.: $\neg A(x)$
\end{document}
```

In the terminal I run

```
make4ht text_file
```

My original pdf looks like this [image]

But the html does this [image]

So I have two issues: I figured out that the first problem comes from the \section{} command in latex. If I take the section out, the text below the first formula looks good again: How can I tell make4ht to deal with sections? (I could also remove the Book 1 headline, I dont need it) My second issue is that the formula gets treated differently. The left side is converted to an image and thus looks fine in the html, the right side is somehow converted to text and doesnt look good anymore. Is there a smart way to fix this? (I am dealing with 500 pages filled with formulas, so every automation that is done right will save me a lot of time)

The output in the terminal I get is the following

```
[STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion started
[STATUS]  make4ht: Input file: text_file
[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename Line    Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht  30133    LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document} in `'.
[ERROR]   htlatex: /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht  30133    LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document} in `'.
[ERROR]   htlatex: /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht  30135    LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document} in `'.
[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename Line    Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht  30133    LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document} in `'.
[ERROR]   htlatex: /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht  30133    LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document} in `'.
[ERROR]   htlatex: /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht  30135    LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document} in `'.
[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename Line    Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht  30133    LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document} in `'.
[ERROR]   htlatex: /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht  30133    LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document} in `'.
[ERROR]   htlatex: /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht  30135    LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document} in `'.
[STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion finished
```

I have Ubuntu 20.04 and use Tex Live 2020 if that matters. Help will be greatly appreciated, thank you! :)

Comment: I don't get this error with up to date teX Live 2020.

Comment: interesting.. how can I test this? tex ---version gives me: TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2020) kpathsea version 6.3.2 ... Is there a way to update Tex Live without reinstalling it completely?

Comment: you can try to get just the updated .4ht files from here https://www.kodymirus.cz/files/ you will need in particular html4.4ht, html5.4ht, tex4ht.sty and memoir.4ht. but it is possible that you will run to other issues due to version mismatch.

Comment: ok i will try that. Thank you! :)

Comment: I hope it helps. Other than that is to hope that Ubuntu updates their TeX Live version :)